# $_REQUEST data different from $_POST in HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, request

This is the very first time I post here but this one is really making me crazy!

In an input - text form in HTML i got different data from REQUEST and POST methods.

Anybody can help me with this really basic thing!?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you post the results of the data and the html for the form. Otherwise, there's simply no way we can help you.

Comment: Sorry Difster, here it goes.      echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_REQUEST);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);

Comment: array(5) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(10) "1502502356"
  ["email"]=>
  string(15) "email@email.com"
  ["password"]=>
  string(9) "asd123456"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(4) "send"
  ["PHPSESSID"]=>
  string(32) "89dd0a44b8fe382a2d54bee392a58a01"
}
array(4) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(8) "userName"
  ["email"]=>
  string(15) "email@email.com"
  ["password"]=>
  string(9) "asd123456"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(4) "send"
}